# Mostrar un mensaje cuando la tabla (table html) este vacía

Tags: html, css

Mi consulta es la siguiente, tengo una tabla que muestra datos cuando se cumple una condición, y cuando esta condición no se cumple la tabla no muestra nada. El tema es que cuando no muestra nada quiero agregarle un mensaje que indique tal situación (o sea que aparezca un mensaje que diga SIN DATOS). Intente hacerlo a través de CSS y el problema es que la tabla tenga o no tenga datos siempre me muestra el mensaje SIN DATOS.

Esta es la tabla:

```html
 <table class="table">
            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th>
                        DNI
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Apellido
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Nombre
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Categoria de Aplicacion
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Fecha Aplicacion
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Vacuna
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Dosis
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Tiempo Interdosis
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Esquema
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Lote
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Fecha Proxima Vacunacion
                    </th>
                </tr>

                @foreach (var vacunacion in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @vacunacion.DNI
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @vacunacion.Apellido
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @vacunacion.Nombre
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @vacunacion.CategoriaAplicacion
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", vacunacion.FechaAplicacion))
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @vacunacion.NombreVacuna
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @vacunacion.NombreDosis
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @vacunacion.TiempoInterdosis
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @vacunacion.Esquema
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @vacunacion.Lote
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", vacunacion.FechaProxVac))
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                }
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
```

Y este es el codigo de CSS que estoy utilizando para mostrar el mensaje SIN DATOS:

```css
table > tbody:empty {
    position: relative;
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    text-align: center;
}

    table > tbody:empty:before {
        content: 'SIN DATOS';
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 12px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Comment: Buen día, por la estructura de tu `HTML` creo que está en un archivo `blade` si es así en lugar de `foreach` podrías utilizar un `forelse` en lugar de hacerlo con `css`

Comment: Hola HeytalePazguato, muchas gracias por responder. El HTML no lo tengo en un archivo blade.

Comment: ¿Qué framework usas? Pero igual puedes utilizar un `forelse`, de esa forma mostraría la tabla si hay datos y si no creas una nueva fila que diga que no hay datos.

Answer (score 1):

No se si usas un Framework (como Laravel por ejemplo) pero voy a darte un ejemplo usando Laravel y PHP normal, tu lo adecuas a tu modo.

Según veo **vacunacion** es tu variable clave, entonces lo que debes hacer es un condicional antes de "pintar" toda la tabla. Algo así:

```
@if(vacunacion) // Laravel
if(vacunacion){ // PHP Normal
    <table class="table">
        <thead>

            <tr>
                <th>
                    DNI
                </th>
                <th>
                    Apellido
                </th>
                <th>
                    Nombre
                </th>
                <th>
                    Categoria de Aplicacion
                </th>
                <th>
                    Fecha Aplicacion
                </th>
                <th>
                    Vacuna
                </th>
                <th>
                    Dosis
                </th>
                <th>
                    Tiempo Interdosis
                </th>
                <th>
                    Esquema
                </th>
                <th>
                    Lote
                </th>
                <th>
                    Fecha Proxima Vacunacion
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var vacunacion in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @vacunacion.DNI
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @vacunacion.Apellido
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @vacunacion.Nombre
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @vacunacion.CategoriaAplicacion
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", vacunacion.FechaAplicacion))
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @vacunacion.NombreVacuna
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @vacunacion.NombreDosis
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @vacunacion.TiempoInterdosis
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @vacunacion.Esquema
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @vacunacion.Lote
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", vacunacion.FechaProxVac))
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
}
else{ // PHP Normal
@else // Laravel
    No hay datos para mostrar
@endif // Laravel
} // PHP Normal
```

En resumen, con in **IF** condicionas que si no hay registros en **vacunacion** se muestre el texto o muestre una imagen o lo que tu quieras.